# Customizer sanitize_callback for input type number

Tags: theme-customizer, sanitization

How to sanitize input control with `"type" => "number"`. It would better if somebody actually explain in detail sanitize_callback on customizer.

Answer (score 6):

Add a setting, specifying the `sanitize_callback`:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'my_input',
    array(
        'default' => '100.00',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_float',
    )
);
```

Add the control:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'my_input',
    array(
        'label' => 'Please enter a number:',
        'section' => 'my_section',
        'type' => 'number',
        'input_attrs' => array(
            'min' => '0.01', 'step' => '0.01', 'max' => '10000',
          ),
    )
);
```

Create a function to perform the sanitisation - `filter_var` should return the sanitised float or `false`:

```
function sanitize_float( $input ) {
    return filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
}
```

This is untested, but should get you started - it could, of course, be adapted to sanitize an integer.

[Adapted from http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer/]

Comment: I had tried using 'floatval' but was getting a null response. After using this 'sanitize_float' function I started getting valid responses (when changing a value in a customizer control, which used this function to sanitize the value)