# Customizer: How to Sanitize a Decimal Number Range

Tags: php, theme-development, theme-customizer

I have the following Customizer control/settings to control an image's opacity:

```
// Image Opacity
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'image_opacity', array(
    'default'           => '1.000',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'my_theme_sanitize_number_range'
) );
$wp_customize->add_control( 'image_opacity', array(
    'label'             => __( 'Image Opacity', 'my-theme' ),
    'type'              => 'range',
    'input_attrs'       => array(
        'min'           => 0,
        'max'           => 1.000,
        'step'          => 0.001,
    ),
) );
```

and the following sanitize function:

```
// Sanitize Number Range
function my_theme_sanitize_number_range( $number, $setting ) {
    $number = absint( $number );
    $atts = $setting->manager->get_control( $setting->id )->input_attrs;
    $min = ( isset( $atts['min'] ) ? $atts['min'] : $number );
    $max = ( isset( $atts['max'] ) ? $atts['max'] : $number );
    $step = ( isset( $atts['step'] ) ? $atts['step'] : 0.001 );
    return ( $min <= $number && $number <= $max && is_int( $number / $step ) ? $number : $setting->default );
}
```

It works fine for whole numbers, like if `'max' => 1,` and `'step' => 1` but I want the steps to three decimal points like `'step' => 0.001`, which doesn't work.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225825/customizer-sanitize-callback-for-input-type-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the call of `absint` at beginning. you should do more debugging to avoid this mistake.

after that the division `$number / $step` always returns a float. then to round the value, use something like that :

```
$number = floor($number / $atts['step']) * $atts['step'];

return ( $min <= $number && $number <= $max ) ? $number : $setting->default;
```

Comment: unfortunately that does not work

Comment: you need to remove the call of absint at beginning.